# Rails. save_and_open_page in lynx browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vagrant

For testing my app, I use rspec, launchy, capybara, capybara-webkit. When I use `save_and_open_page` in vagrant mashine, have error:

```
Failure/Error: save_and_open_page

     Launchy::CommandNotFoundError:
       Unable to find a browser command. If this is unexpected, Please rerun with environment variable LAUNCHY_DEBUG=true or the '-d' commandline option and file a bug at https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/new
```

Lynx is installed. Launchy must able to use console browser: 
https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy/issues/93

How can open page in console browser without GUI?

Comment: what is your `Capybara.default_driver` ?

Comment: capybara-webkit